# How to wait for some operation in another class to start next operation in c#?

Tags: c#

I know you don't understand the question title. Let me tell you the whole scenario.

I have a class named as Processor. Processor can get notifiable steps or send notification to other application API depending on some condition. Like as below:

```
Method: SendOrStartProcess(Operation operation)

Method Implementation:

If(operation.steps.any(o=>o.canProcess)){
    _service.notify(operations);   //This is fine
}
else{
    var totalSteps = await _service.getAdjustableSteps(); //It returns the adjustable steps and will invoke event which is subscribed by another class named as GetAdjustableStepsEnd. It can be invoked immediately or after some time.
    //Set totalSteps in operationsc.steps and save in database and that's it.
 

}
```

Now, I have another class named as "OperationHandler" which subscirbed the GetAdjustableStepsEnd event.

```
public OperationHandler(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            
            _agent.GetAdjustableStepsEnd += GetAdjustableStepsEnd ;
            
        }

        public async void GetAdjustableStepsEnd (object sender, GetAdjustableStepsEndEventArgs e)
        {
            // Here i will call again the above method _processor.SendOrStartProcess(e.Operations);
        }
```

//Now the problem is if event invokes after some time then it is fine because meanwhile i set the status in database. But if it invoked just after the getAdjustableSteps then i call SendOrStartProcess again and it sends getAdjustableSteps again because record is not set in the database. How to overcome this situation. I can not put lock on it because this is used by many clients.

Comment: So you only call SendOrStartProcess if you havent saved the value to the database? Cant you assume that the value must have been saved when the event happens?

Comment: No. I can't because it can invoke any time.